# Eclipse C++: Build successfully but the binary file is not generated

Tags: c++, eclipse, googletest

I tried to follow some tutorials of using google test in Eclipse. I created a project named **unit_test**. It seems that everything is OK. I could build the project successfully. 
However, **there is nothing generated in Binaries folder**. 
I used Eclipse on Mac, and Cross GCC tool chain. Here is the log when I built the project:

```
make all 
Building file: ../test/gtest_main.cpp
Invoking: Cross G++ Compiler
g++ -I"/Users/kien/workspaceCPP/unit_test/include" -I"/Users/kien/workspaceCPP/unit_test/gtest_src" -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"test/gtest_main.d" -MT"test/gtest_main.o" -o "test/gtest_main.o" "../test/gtest_main.cpp"
Finished building: ../test/gtest_main.cpp

Building file: ../src/factorial.cpp
Invoking: Cross G++ Compiler
g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/factorial.d" -MT"src/factorial.o" -o "src/factorial.o" "../src/factorial.cpp"
Finished building: ../src/factorial.cpp

Building file: ../gtest_src/gtest/gtest-all.cc
Invoking: Cross G++ Compiler
g++ -I"/Users/kien/workspaceCPP/unit_test/gtest_src" -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -  fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"gtest_src/gtest/gtest-all.d" - MT"gtest_src/gtest/gtest-all.o" -o "gtest_src/gtest/gtest-all.o"  "../gtest_src/gtest/gtest-all.cc"
Finished building: ../gtest_src/gtest/gtest-all.cc

Building target: unit_test
Invoking: Cross G++ Linker
g++  -o "unit_test"  ./test/gtest_main.o  ./src/factorial.o  ./gtest_src/gtest/gtest-all.o   -lpthread
Finished building target: unit_test
```

I notice that there is a Debug folder generated in my project and under that folder, there is a file called *unit_test*. If I use the Terminal to run that unit_test file, it looks like running the test program I would expected. But I don't know why I cannot run this project as usual, e.g. binary file generated and I click the Run button. Could you please help with that?

Answer (score 0):

I changed from  Cross GCC Tool chain to MacOSX GCC and the problem's solved. 
Don't know why :(